# Trimming the names of long file names [Rename]

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have quite a lot of files I need to rename. All tutorials I saw only lists appending something to the old filename. For example from `abc.txt` to `unix_abc.txt` or `abc_unix.txt`. I know that I have to use regular expressions, but I am not able to write the exact expression.

```
for FILENAME in *; do mv $FILENAME {SOME_EXPRESSION_HERE}; done
```

How to write that expression? I could of think of this expression

```
Unix_Unix_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_without_dash_file.pdf
```

My file names are

```
Unix_Unix_1_without_dash_file.pdf
Unix_Unix_10_without_dash_file.pdf
Unix_Unix_100_without_dash_file.pdf
```

I need it to be like

```
1.pdf
10.pdf
100.pdf
```

That is only the number which is between the filename.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This thread could help: https://serverfault.com/questions/348482/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following command and let me know if this helps you. I am printing `mv` commands as of now you could remove `echo` in case of you feel it is correct.

```
for file in Unix*.pdf
do
   temp="${file/_without*/}"
   echo "mv $file ${temp##*_}.pdf"
done
```

Output will be as follows.

```
mv Unix_Unix_100_without_dash_file.pdf 100.pdf
mv Unix_Unix_10_without_dash_file.pdf 10.pdf
mv Unix_Unix_1_without_dash_file.pdf 1.pdf
```

***NOTE:*** As mentioned above once you are happy with above command remove `echo` from `echo "mv $file ${temp##*_}.pdf"` line and then change it to `mv "$file"  "${temp##*_}.pdf"` it will rename those files then.